# Inner join 2 tables into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, vertica, jet

I have 2 tables, trying to `inner join` into one table. I am using Excel to query, so it has limited syntax (Jet Access). `stack1` and `stack2` tables are identical and in two different Excel sheets.

The tables come from Vertica (`stack1` and `stack2`) and SQL Server (`overflow`), then I am trying an internal query to combine the tables.

Here is what I have tried, I am getting a syntax error on this, not sure where I am going wrong:

```
select *
from [stack1$], [stack2$]
INNER JOIN [overflow$]
ON [stack1$].[iddate] = [overflow$].[iddate]
AND [stack1$].[idbusiness] = [overflow$].[idbusiness]
AND [stack2$].[iddate] = [overflow$].[iddate]
AND [stack2$].[idbusiness] = [overflow$].[idbusiness]
```

If I do just one table like so, it works fine:

```
select *
from [stack1$]
INNER JOIN [overflow$]
ON [stack1$].[iddate] = [overflow$].[iddate]
AND [stack1$].[idbusiness] = [overflow$].[idbusiness]
```

Sample data:

Overflow:

```
 +----------+------------+---------+
|  iddate  | idbusiness | otherid |
+----------+------------+---------+
| 20180209 |   95971462 |    5235 |
+----------+------------+---------+
```

Stack 1:

```
+------------+-------+----------+
| idbusiness | value |  iddate  |
+------------+-------+----------+
|   95971462 |       | 20180209 |
|   95971462 |       | 20180209 |
|   95971462 |       | 20180209 |
|   95971462 |       | 20180209 |
|   95971462 |       | 20180209 |
|   95971462 |       | 20180209 |
|   95971462 |       | 20180209 |
|   95971462 | 10.04 | 20180209 |
+------------+-------+----------+
```

The above query gives me:

```
+--------------------+-------+----------------+---------+
| stack1$.idbusiness | value | stack1$.iddate | otherid |
+--------------------+-------+----------------+---------+
|           95971462 |       |       20180209 |    5235 |
|           95971462 |       |       20180209 |    5235 |
|           95971462 |       |       20180209 |    5235 |
|           95971462 |       |       20180209 |    5235 |
|           95971462 |       |       20180209 |    5235 |
|           95971462 | 10.04 |       20180209 |    5235 |
|           95971462 |       |       20180209 |    5235 |
|           95971462 |       |       20180209 |    5235 |
+--------------------+-------+----------------+---------+
```

Now I want to add `Stack 2` to this, which will contain the same columns as `stack1` but different `idbusiness` then in `stack1`. Also looks like `iddate` is not needed, all records are the same date.

Comment: What is the underlying database?

Comment: @GordonLinoff ,  the tables come from Vertica (stack 1 and stack 2) and SQL Server (overflow) then I am trying to internal query to combine the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Gordon said, it's not recommended to mix implicit and explicit joins in the same query. Here is how your query is written with implicit joins:

```
SELECT *
FROM [overflow$], [stack1$], [stack2$]
WHERE [stack1$].[iddate] = [overflow$].[iddate]
  AND [stack1$].[idbusiness] = [overflow$].[idbusiness]
  AND [stack2$].[iddate] = [overflow$].[iddate]
  AND [stack2$].[idbusiness] = [overflow$].[idbusiness]
```

For the sake of completeness, here is how your query is written with explicit joins (as in Gordon's answer, but using your naming style):

```
SELECT *
FROM ([overflow$]
      INNER JOIN [stack1$]
              ON [stack1$].[iddate] = [overflow$].[iddate]
             AND [stack1$].[idbusiness] = [overflow$].[idbusiness])
INNER JOIN [stack2$]
        ON [stack2$].[iddate] = [overflow$].[iddate]
       AND [stack2$].[idbusiness] = [overflow$].[idbusiness]
```

It is generally recommended to use explicit joins. Sadly, the Jet syntax requires parentheses for joins, which makes it harder to write & read.

If those conditions are correct, the two queries above should be identical and give you the same results. However, some database have issues/bugs with the implicit joins, so the results (mainly performance) may vary. I don't know about Vertica, but for recent versions of SQL Server, there should be no difference.

If you're not getting records from the above queries, then the conditions are probably wrong. I suspect that you actually want the results of two queries combined with `UNION`:

```
SELECT *
FROM [overflow$]
INNER JOIN [stack1$]
        ON [stack1$].[iddate] = [overflow$].[iddate]
       AND [stack1$].[idbusiness] = [overflow$].[idbusiness]
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM [overflow$]
INNER JOIN [stack2$]
        ON [stack2$].[iddate] = [overflow$].[iddate]
       AND [stack2$].[idbusiness] = [overflow$].[idbusiness]
```

Comment: your union query seems to crash my excel or take very long. The others above return quickly but 0 result just headers. I've posted some sample data.

Comment: If you do the query with `[stack1$]` alone as you mentioned in you question, how many records do you get? And if you do it with `[stack2$]`? If those two separate query return reasonable number of records (a few hundreds or thousands), then the `UNION` should run fine. You can try `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`, but that will eliminate all duplicate records, so it depends on what you want the results to be.

Comment: `overflow` has 5k records, `stack1` has 950k records. The result of joining them gets around 250k records, but it takes 10 minutes. I think this has to do with the size, `stack2` i cannot even run on its own, but when I shrink it down it queries nicely.  I'm going to have to shrink my data set i think then join.

Comment: That's obviously the problem, if you cannot even run `stack2` on its own, then you won't be able to add it with `UNION`. Even if you shrink it and, if it produces 250k in 10 minutes similar to `stack1`, then the `UNION` will give 500k in about 20 minutes. That's a lot. You can shrink the data, but more importantly you need to create indexes on the `[iddate]` and `[idbusiness]` columns in all the 3 tables. This should reduce the time significantly to probably a minute or two for the full `UNION` query.

Comment: what do you mean create indexes? How do I do that?

Comment: If those 3 tables are coming directly from the databases, you need to go the databases and create index for the columns I mentioned. If you don't know how to create indexes, you need to google it for SQL Server & Vertica. This question is too broad to be answered here.

Comment: thanks for your help, i'm going to mark your answer as correct as it technically is correct, its just a huge amount of data in excel issue. Thanks again.

Comment: why did you use brackets in the first inner join but not the second? Referring to your 2nd block of code?

Comment: That's the syntax for the Jet engine. You can use brackets for the second one, but it's not required. If you have 5 joins, then you must use brackets for the 4 inner ones, and the 5th outer one is not required.

Answer (score 2):

Try Union, it will you the unique rows of (overflow$ join stack1$) union (overflow$ join stack2).

```
SELECT * FROM [overflow$]
JOIN [stack1$]
ON [stack1$].[iddate] = [overflow$].[iddate]
AND [stack1$].[idbusiness] = [overflow$].[idbusiness]
        UNION 
SELECT * FROM [overflow$]
JOIN [stack2$]
ON [stack2$].[iddate] = [overflow$].[iddate]
AND [stack2$].[idbusiness] = [overflow$].[idbusiness]
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix old-style and new-style joins.

Something like this should work:

```
select *
from ([overflow$] as o inner join
      [stack1$] as s1
      on s1.[iddate] = o.[iddate] and
         s1.[idbusiness] = o.[idbusiness]
     ) inner join
     [stack2$] as s2
     on s2.[iddate] = o.[iddate] and
        s2.[idbusiness] = o.[idbusiness];
```

I wrote this using MS Access syntax.  The parentheses are not needed in other databases.

Comment: The technical term from the "old-style" joins is "full join" (also called "cross join"). If you add a `WHERE` clause for the joining condition, then it is called "equi-join". When comparing the "old-style" to the "new-style", we often refer to them as "implicit joins" vs. "explicit joins".

Comment: @GordonLinoff , thank you for the answer, the query you provided works, as in no error, but no values , but I do get headers returned.  When I do the one table join (shown above) I do have records returned.

Comment: If you're getting no records then the conditions that you're using are incorrect. Post some example data for the 3 tables and your expected output so we can help you better, otherwise we have no way to tell what the correct conditions must be.

Comment: @RacilHilan, I have posted some sample data